# Pee Shiver: Any reliable research about this phenomenon?

Tags: human-physiology, autonomic-nervous-system

I came across 2 webpages about the science of pee shiver.

[Link 1](http://www.nbcnews.com/health/body-odd/pee-shivers-you-know-youre-curious-f688401)
[Link 2](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-it-that-sometimes-when-I-pee-I-get-the-shivers)

I wonder if there any reliable scientific research about this phenomenon. The 2 webpages I have hyperlinked attribute this to ANS(Automatic Nervous System) or sudden decrease of temperature in exposed body part while peeing.

But these 2 are just hypotheses, not proved reseach. Is there any?

Comment: Sadly, nobody really knows why this happens. Interestingly, those 2 links are the only 2 major theories about this :P

Comment: @another 'Homo sapien' I think the hypothesis of relating pee shiver to autonomous nervous system is more realistic.
What do you think?

Comment: Yeah, that temperature one does not seem much satisfactory. However, I did not study either of them in detail, so I can't approve any right now...maybe somebody would also like to share opinion ;)

Comment: Really is there such a phenomenon? I never perceived it yet.

Comment: @Always Confused Yes, there is. I frequently perceive it.

Comment: @Mockingbird Maybe because I live in a very hot climate. Yet I never perceived it when I was in tour to any Himalayan region. BTW I could not found any wikipedia article on it. May be that has been not created yet, or maybe that exist in some other technical names.

Comment: It's been found that many people don't notice this phenomenon with themselves.

Comment: @Always Confused Perhaps you should try drinking too much water, then holding your bladder for too long, then pee. you might perceive it. And speaking of hot climate, I live in a tropical climate. Yet, I perceive it